# How to fix the window of Audience video player in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, unity, gui, video-player, elementary

I have used elementary OS in the past and wanted to keep an eye on its light but interesting video player Audience, and test it in Ubuntu, as indicated in [this post](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/audience-media-player-getting-closer-to.html).

But after installing it, its window doesn't look good.

[image]

It should look like this

[image]

What  could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu theme doesn't work well with headerbars, so it looks weird. Try a different theme, like Adwaita or elementary.

The second screenshot shows an old version of Audience; at the time it looked like this in Ubuntu.